# Two-way databinding options?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, mvvm

The current codebase I'm working with is very tied to Prototype+scriptaculous. When I look at software like Backbone or Knockout I commonly see dependencies on jquery+underscore, which seem to conflict with what I've got. What options have I got? I'm mostly after something like Knockout, but I guess two-way databinding would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Angular's scope objects](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope). It great for two-way databinding. See more detail at [Most useful techniques for two way data binding with js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632935/most-useful-techniques-for-two-way-data-binding-with-js/9902074#9902074).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Lava JS.  It provides rich two way databinding and does not appear to have any dependencies.  http://lava.codeplex.com